# Word Add-in Shared Run time is not working

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

we have created a word office add-in, which reads data from the SharePoint library and adds inside the Word file when opened from SharePoint Library, We have used shared run time inside the word office add-in, But it is not working at the first time when the document gets opened the second time, it is working.

Comment: What does that mean `But it is not working`? Do you get any errors at runtime? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Try to unblock files downloaded from the internet before opening like shown on the picture:

[image: unblock files downloaded from internet]

Hope that helps.

Also you may try posting this as an issue to https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues.